# Is Docker Maximum container size 100GB?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-machine

I am working on Hyperledger Fabric ver 1.4, my server freeze when many transactions are been done. My understanding is that the old transactions or versions which are committed do not get removed but stay in the docker using disk space ( I might be wrong on this assumption ) therefore the only solution I have yet found is increasing my virtual server disk space to 120GB. 100GB for docker and 20GB to run my Front-end development.

I have looked into Alpine images but right now I do not want to take that route.

With Current Configurations I have 75GB SSD and 4GB of RAM

- Is there a way to decrease the Max Disk size been used in Ubuntu
  16.04 LTS 64bit Minimal?
- If not, is the Maximum container size 100GB in Docker?

In GUI interface I can increase and decrease the size as show in the attached image.

[GUI Interface Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCogx.png)

Comment: One comment. Transactions, of course, are stored in blocks and never removed (it is a blockchain). The state is stored on LevelDB or CouchDB (normally CouchDB on production) and documents can be removed. The more indexes you define (in CouchDB), the more space it takes. Previous versions of documents are stored in LevelDB (never CouchDB), but can be disabled by setting `CORE_LEDGER_HISTORY_ENABLEHISTORYDATABASE` to `false`.

Comment: And I am not a docker expert, but if there is some problem with sizes, it should be with the volume sizes, not with the container or image sizes.

Comment: Also I would like to add that it is probably within your application logic if the docker image gets to big. It is most likely not an issue with docker.